# How close do links have to be to trigger link preview in Chrome beta?

Tags: android, css, google-chrome

Some of the users of my website are telling me they find it annoying when they try to touch certain links and instead of activating the link it zooms into the link and associated metadata (which is made up of a few links).

So how many css pixels of separation are needed between the link and the associated data to stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I also would like to know that, and eventually a js/css trick to disable it on demand.

You can also have a look at this question :
[How to prevent google chrome android browser to display the magnifier when users click a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972106/how-to-prevent-google-chrome-android-browser-to-display-the-magnifier-when-users?answertab=oldest#tab-top)