# How to prevent google chrome android browser to display the magnifier when users click a button?

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, browser

I'm building a simple html menu with unordered lists and I'm trying to prevent google chrome browser to display its magnifier every time I click a link.

The browser considers the `li`'s to be too close from each other for the user to click it accurately. But I disagree!

How could I disable/cancel/prevent this behavior, other than setting a bigger padding on the `li` elements please? Is there even a way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think I found a way and it's so stupid I don't know how I didn't think of it sooner...

Just change the `viewport` meta tag to disable zooming on the page and the magnifier feature won't bother you anymore.

i.e.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
```

I tested this on Galaxy Nexus and Galaxy Note with success. Any other input and feedback is welcome!

[EDIT]

After experimenting a lot with mobile UX I'd advise to... **DESIGN BIGGER BUTTONS!**

Comment: Thanks @Armel, Helped me alot. How did you get that?

Comment: Is it possible to do it without the 'user-scalable=no'. I **want** users to be able to zoom. However I do **not want** the zoom overlay to popup on button clicks? Thanks

Comment: Not that I know of. I'd have edited my answer ;-)
Make bigger buttons!

Comment: Armel, you have made my day!

Comment: however this breaks the layout when page is autorotated, so I have left only <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no" /> and it works ok for me.

Comment: @user2190488 - I asked a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41143080/how-to-prevent-android-chrome-magnifier-link-preview-when-when-user-clicks-on) with a slight difference - site isn't responsive so disabling zoom isn't an option - any other ideas ? Did you figure a way out ?

Comment: I have noticed that only the `width=device-width` bears significance in my case. My users can still zoom, but now this horendous onClick zoom is gone

Comment: Will try this and edit the answer. which version of the browser are you running?

Comment: "user-scalable=no" didn't work for me in Android 5.1.1. But it only happens in fancybox iframe, and nomatter how big I make the buttons. Need to test to see if it happens also in any old iframe.

Comment: Oh. Further to... the error was in the page that launches my fancybox iframe, There, on advise gleaned not sure when/where, I had set maximum-scale=0.8 (on the iframed pages it was maximum-scale=1.0).  Changing 0.8 to 1.0 fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to disable this as it is a feature of the Android Chrome browser.

Unfortunately, the source code for Android Chrome browser isn't open source (yet) so I can't take a look.

You may find it useful to report a bug here: [new.mcrbug.com](http://new.mcrbug.com)

Answer (score -1):

It seems to work with this CSS declaration:

```
-webkit-touch-callout:none;
```

Comment: Tested in latest Chrome for Android, it's not preventing the magnifier when tapping on things.

Comment: This appears to be a [Safari only CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-touch-callout). As it has no support in other webkit browsers, this won't help with Chrome.