# Android Chrome - Deactivate magnification when links are close

Tags: android, google-chrome, meta-tags, magnification

Using Android 4.1.1 Google Chrome, when I try to click on small links that are close together a magnified view of these links pops open.

Is there a way to deactivate this, either in the settings or in the CSS / meta tags?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125851/enable-disable-zoom-in-android-webview

Answer (score 2):

When you have control over the meta tags, the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972106/how-to-prevent-google-chrome-android-browser-to-display-the-magnifier-when-users?answertab=oldest#tab-top) will work. However it will also remove the ability to zoom in/out, and change the initial zoom level, so may not be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I've not verified it, but [this article](http://www.chromestory.com/chrome-for-android-a-mini-user-guide/) claims that there is a setting called **Enable link preview**:

> Enable link preview: Magnify links when it’s unclear which link you pressed.

Comment: I don't see this setting in Chrome.

Comment: I don't see it, either

Answer (score 0):

Try this library 
Sometimes it has to do with the double click gesture, which conflicts with the on click events assigned to the html elements, in many cases, this replacement of clicks for taps, helps.

https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick